# DML trigger, creating new rows for several customers after insert/update/delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am using SQL Server 2017.

**What I want to achieve**: The database contains tables for customers, coupon codes and suppliers. A customer is a company. A customer may be an independent company, it may belong to another company, and it may have "child companies" (the connection between child and parent companies are established through a ParentID column in the customers table).

Coupon codes are related to customers. When a "parent company" activates access a coupon code, the code is supposed to become available for all the parent company's child companies. Likewise, if a parent company deactivates access to a coupon code, child companies should also lose access. As of today, this has to be fixed manually. I am writing a trigger that will take over this manual task.

A table **CompanyCodes** stores the relationship between companies and coupon codes. Column "Customer" stores the company ID number, column "Supplier" stores the ID of the supplier of the coupon code and column "Code" stores the coupon code.

Whenever a row is inserted, updated or deleted into/from the CompanyCodes table, the trigger first checks whether or not the relevant customer has any child companies. If it does, the trigger is supposed to insert/update/delete a row for each of the company's child companies, so that the changes are reflected in all of them.

E.g. customer 1 is the parent of customer 2 and customer 3. Customer 1 activates access to a new coupon code for supplier X, and a new row is inserted into CompanyCodes with the relevant information. In this case, the trigger is supposed to insert two new rows into the table, one for customer 2 and one for customer 3, where all the information (except the company ID) is the same as what was inserted for customer 1.

**Where I am stuck:** How do I make this work in cases where the customer has several child companies?

Here's the relevant part of my query as it currently stands (this is all within a IF statement that is executed when the trigger-firing action is "INSERTED")

```
DECLARE @insertedSupplier AS INT
DECLARE @insertedCode AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @insertedSupplier = (SELECT Supplier FROM inserted)
SET @insertedCode = (SELECT Code FROM inserted)


    INSERT INTO dbo.CompanyCodes (Customer, Supplier, Code)
    VALUES ((SELECT id FROM Customers WHERE Customers.ParentID = (SELECT Customer FROM inserted))
            ,@insertedSupplier, @insertedCode)
```

If there was a maximum of one possible child company, the above should work. But when there are several, "(SELECT id FROM Customers WHERE Customers.ParentID = (SELECT Customer FROM inserted)" will return several rows.

What would be simplest (and preferably best practice?) way of doing what I want to do here?

**Edit with example showing desired output:**

Customers table

```
| Customer | ID | ParentID |
|----------|----|----------|
|Customer1 |  1 | NULL     | 
|Customer2 |  2 |   1      |
|Customer3 |  3 |   1      |
```

Customer1 then proceeds to activate access to a new coupon code, and the CompanyCodes table changes to the following:

```
| Customer | Supplier |   Code   |
|----------|----------|----------|
|Customer1 |  123456  | abcdefgh |
```

The trigger then fires, and adds one row for each of Customer1's two child companies (where all the info, except for the Customer name, is the same as for Customer1):

```
| Customer | Supplier |   Code   |
|----------|----------|----------|
|Customer1 |  123456  | abcdefgh | 
|Customer2 |  123456  | abcdefgh |
|Customer3 |  123456  | abcdefgh |
```

**Edit 2:** Also, the way our systems work, there is never more than one single insert/update/delete of a row in the CompanyCodes table (no batch jobs)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Get ride of `SELECT Supplier FROM inserted` and use a proper JOIN. It doesn't do what you think it doing.

Comment: I *suppose* at least this trigger will fail when the OP's DML statement affects 2+ rows, @Sami , unlike what we normally see, where only the "last" row has any processes run against it.

Comment: Yup, I didn't read the whole Q @Larnu tbh, it's the first thing I've seen. There's a lot of wrong things there, but as can see, I don't think anyone can help with the given informations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added a desired result (for an INSERT example). I'm afraid I don't have sample data, this is from our production DB (table names and columns are all made up).

Comment: @Sami: I added an example for the desired results, which hopefully makes things a bit clearer. Why is it that the "SELECT Supplier FROM inserted" of the SET insertedSupplier will not work? And how would I be able replace it with a join here?

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)